# Errors upon opening terminal on tclsh and module

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, tcl, tclsh

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, kernel 4.15.0-34-generic. I am a fairly new user and upon installing a bunch of software (that I've lost track of, unfortunately) for my new project, I suddenly got these two lines appearing every time I open the terminal:

```
/usr/share/modules/init/bash: line 36: /usr/bin/tclsh: No such file or directory
/usr/share/modules/init/bash: line 60: export: module: not a function`
```

I can ignore them and continue my work normally, or so it seems, but there's obviously something wrong. I spent the last few hours trying to wrap my head around this, but didn't manage to make them go away.

I think this is related to me installing environmental modules, but I don't remember what I might have done wrong, so it is difficult to trace back.
 Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: [environment modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: what does `ls -l /usr/bin/tclsh*` show? You might need to `sudo apt install tcl`

Comment: @glennjackman Amazing. I can't believe, of all things, that *this* was what I forgot to do. Thank you for taking the time to look into my stupidity. :)

Comment: No, not stupidity. Everyone forgets to do stuff. Too bad the module command doesn't provide a nicer warning. However, it is worthwhile to look closely at the error messages you get and think about what they mean: "'No such file', hmm, why is that? Do I really have /usr/bin/tclsh?"

Comment: After installing tcl it appeared there. Previously it was missing, and I think that caused all the errors. I had tcslh8.6 and that's why I probably thought I had installed it and didn't dwell on it.

Comment: You may want to answer the question yourself? And give some credits to glenn by up-voting his helpful comments?

Comment: @mrcalvin I would, but I think my rep is too low to upvote comments on stack overflow..

Comment: Yea, it's a [privilege granted at 15 pts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I needed to do in the was write

```
sudo apt install tcl
```

For whatever reason, I managed to forget to type that with everything I was doing. Thanks to glenn jackman.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following error after assigning the private key and log in in X2GO (Mac os Ventura) and the problem was resolved by installing the **tcl** in the  remote server (Ubuntu 18.04):

Error: Connection failed. /usr/share/modules/init/bash: line 36: /usr/bin/tclsh: No such file or directory /usr/share/modules/init/bash: line 60: export: module: not a function /usr/share/modules/init/bash: line 36: /usr/bin/tclsh: No such file or directory /usr/share/modules/init/bash: line 60: export: module: not a function

Solution: sudo apt install tcl

Make sure log in as root user!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).